# User entry point after quiting the onboarding process

Tags: mobile, navigation, onboarding

I am designing the onboarding flow for a mobile application.

The first image below shows a simplified version of the flow. The application consists of two parts; the onboarding for new users and the main application for returning users (after registration).

Users first register as an individual and later register the group (company, family or band for example) they want to use the application with.

**The onboarding screens are as shown below:**

*One - An overview of application USPs.*

*Two - User registration.*

*Three - Group registration.*

[image]

**The problem**

Currently I'm looking at the application entry points for when the user exits the onboarding process and returns later.

The simplified flow above is a 'happy flow'. The users do what we want them to. This is of course too good to be true. Users can exit the application whenever they like.

**Should the user return to the exact position(/screen) in the onboarding process when he returns after closing the application?**

The onboarding process is especially designed for the first run. In an ideal situation the user completes the onboarding in the first run and enters the application via the 'main' view every other time he uses the application.

In the example below the entry point for users who didn't complete the onboarding process is the 'group list' view. This is a view that's accessible from the main application (for registered users to add a second group, for example).

So if a user quits after registering as a user but before registering his group he 'skips' the onboarding upon his return.

**I'm trying to figure out entry points for 'returning first time users' without confusing them about their position in the onboarding process.**

Thanks, guys!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap, I believe the main problems here is that Users quit the onboarding process before finishing it. On return to the app as first time User, though, there is a question if they should come back where they left or return to the beginning of the process, because:

- if they return where they left, they will not see the UVP (and since it could take days when they come back, they may really lose their interest in continuing),
- if they return to the beginning, they will probably get frustrated.

I would suggest:

- **shortening the User onboarding** to minimum, which I think would be two things: logging in (so that they access the app functionality early), and **push notifications approval**,
- from now on, **display the next steps required to achieve 100% functionality in the content they can see within the app** (e.g. *"Discover this app features. Create your group now."*) - this works extremely well with Fecebook-like timelines, you simply create some special cards to support it,
- support it with **push notifications about unfinished process** (e.g. *"You have not completed your profile yet. Come back and do it to make the most of the app."*)